# Зачем использовать недосемантику HTML когда можно ее не использовать?

Tags: html, семантика

Постоянно слышу про семантику и  про то что она необходима. Я совсем не понимаю этого подхода. В *HTML 5* 13 семантических вариаций `div`, и допустим еще всякие списки/кнопки которые были раньше. Тем не менее этого все равно мало и приходится создавать всякие `<div class="card">`. Так почему бы просто не использовать `<div class="footer">` вместо `<footer>`. Так код будет выглядеть однородно и более читабельно чем каша из *HTML* семантичных и самописных элементов.

Вобщем такой вопрос, зачем использовать недосемантику *HTML* когда можно ее не использовать?

Comment: Перейдите по ссылке и найдите в результатах HtmlBook.Ru: https://google.com/search?q=Как+сделать+ссылку. Обратите внимание на дату в сниппете. Теперь откройте исходный код страницы на HtmlBook.Ru и найдите следующее: `<time datetime="2010-09-23">23.09.2010</time>`. С «дивом» не прокатило бы такое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вообще нужна семантика в HTML?

Для того что бы поисковики смогли понимать что у вас есть что. Например `article` или `main` это основные блоки. Классы например `<div class="card">` для поисковиков ничего не значат, это просто название для набора стилей. А вот `article` означает что это сама статья. То есть эти теги помогают роботам и поисковикам понять к чему относится какая часть сайта.

Comment: Это распространяется на все теги внутри article?

Comment: Всё что внутри уже относится к статье, например `header` и `footer` могут входить в `article` как внутренние элементы. Ну и вся разметка внутри.